# How do you search Google for sites that end with similar affix?

Tags: google-search

Anyone knows how to search Google for sites that end with similar prefix? like: site:https://stanford.edu/class/ee{???}
where ??? are 3 digit number

Answer (score 0):

I've looked a bit into it and found that there are only about 20 folders indexed, which have names like `ee+digits`. Those are i.e. cee321, /cs/cs448b, /ee/ee376a, /ee/ee108b and so on. On excluding them one by one with i.e. `-inurl:cee321` i've got them all.

After this i was running some automated `inurl`-queries with additional `filetype:pdf` and found out, that there are about 400 pdf files at all. There are them: https://file.io/ST3ReA

On your primarily question: searching with numbers / number range, like `inurl:1..999` can't be used there, because there are mixed, alphanumeric strings. Advanced search operators can't parse parts of folder name - only full folder names.

Comment: is this how you do it? google: site:https://stanford.edu/class/ inurl:ee